# ofstream variable in name

Tags: c++, filenames, ofstream

I'm trying to create an ofstream and then write values from an array into it.

```
void Graph::toFile(char* filename)
{
    ofstream outfile(filename.c_str()+"_new.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++)
        outfile << graphPartition[i] << endl;
    outfile.close();
}
```

My main problem is, that I want the output file to be named `filename+"new.txt"`. However, there is something wrong with my approach, because i keep getting an error `expression must have class type`.

I'm really sorry, if this question is a duplicate, I haven't found an satisfying solution.

Comment: Replace the `char*` by  `const std::string&`

Comment: And move the call to `c_str()` to after the `+` operator is called first.

Comment: I'm very tempted to flag for closure as being due to a typographic error (trying to use a method of `char *`)... @RemyLebeau The `c_str()` is simply not relevant, no moving required, it just needs to be deleted.

Comment: By the way, if you choose to ignore the advices to replace `char *` with `std::string` and decide to leave it as pointer, then you should replace it with `const char *`. (Because if you don't, then `toFile("blah")` wont work on any modern compiler.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `filename` is not `std::string` it's a c-string (`char*`). C-strings are not objects, they don't have methods, they're just a pointer to a zero-terminated array of characters in memory.

```
filename.c_str()
       -^-
```

The second problem you'd have with this approach, if filename was a std::string, is that adding two C-string pointers doesn't concatenate the strings, it simply does math on the pointers, giving you an address equal to the address returned by filename.c_str() plus the address of "_new.txt"

If you change your code to receive the filename as a std::string

```
void Graph::toFile(std::string filename)
```

then you can do the following:

```
filename += "_new.txt";
```

As follows:

```
void Graph::toFile(std::string filename)
{
    filename += "_new.txt";
    ofstream outfile(filename.c_str());
```

or

```
void Graph::toFile(std::string filename)
{
    ofstream outfile(filename + "_new.txt");
```

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void Graph_toFile(std::string filename)
{
    filename += "_new.txt";
    std::cout << "opening " << filename << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Graph_toFile("hello_world");

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/eAnfZQ